# Concatenate two dataframes with different number of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 shape = (101, 4825)
df2 shape = (97, 5818)
```

The first 4825 column names of `df2` are the same as `df1`, and then increases by +1.

However, at the end of both dataframes, there is a column named `Group_number`.

I want to concatenate both the data frames so that the shape of the final dataframe is of shape (198,5818), i.e the final dataframe has all the rows of both the  and `NaN` values for the `df1` section (after the initial 4825 values).

I tried `pd.concat([df1,df2])` but the column `Group_number` gets mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

This could happening because of index problem as well. Use arg "ignore_index":

```
    pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

or you can test by using "keys" argument so that you will know which observation is of which original data frame:

```
     pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True, keys=['a', 'b'])
```